# Why cant we use <wrapper></wrapper>?

Tags: html

I can use something like `<section id="wrapper"></section>`, however because I'm so pedantic, is there anything wrong with using `<wrapper></wrapper>` as my html element?

I'm using html5 shiv and modernizer, it does work fine however I just wanted to know if there's anything particularly wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: by not specifying an ID, probably the one thing you will lose is the abililty to target css/javascript directly refering to the node. IMHO, it is perfectly fine. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<section>` elements represent a section in the page, not **YOUR LAYOUT**. This is very important and is confused by most of starters in HTML5 including me.

Let me show where you are wrong, using another example:

```
<section id="banner">
</section>
```

Banners are a part of layout not web content. Thus they do not have any section. They have to represented by `<div>` as they used to be in HTML 4.

```
<section id="wrapper">...</section>
```

Is wrong in the same way, because wrappers are purely layout specific tasks, thus it does not represent any specific content on your page. **`<sections>` should always represent differentiated content and not others.**

Here is an example of HTML5, that can be considered valid.

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <section id="mainArticle">

    </section>
    <section id="aboutAuthor">

    </section>
    <aside id="relatedArticles">

    </aside>

</div>
```

Comment: Great, didn't know that,  cheers! I've always used sections as the wrapper, but why shouldn't they be used? Are the semantics too specific or something?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins, Its like wearing a winter hat on legs as socks. It can be used, it will definitely make your feet warm, but is it the correct use? That is what semantic meaning of tags represent :)

Answer (score 3):

Well there is no `wrapper` element in HTML, so yes, that's wrong.  Additionally, the `<section>` element has a specific semantic meaning and should not be used as a generic element wrapper.  Specifically it represents a section of content in the document outline possibly with an appropriate corresponding header and footer. `<div>` has been doing the wrapper job just fine for many years.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own tags will give you an invalid HTML 5 document. It may work, but there are wide-reaching implications (everything from parsers' expectations to browsers' default stylesheets).

As the other answers state, it's not a good use of `section` either.

I suggest setting the [class attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) instead on a `div`. By assigning a class name, you are stating that the element—though somewhat generic— is of that type (almost like instantiating an instance of a class in an object-oriented language).

You can also add [custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#attr-data) to provide further information about the element. These are completely valid and are (emphasis mine):

> ...intended to store custom data private to the page or application,
>   **for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.**

```
<div class="wrapper" data-custom="foo"></div>
```